# My checkbox returns NULL when unchecked

Tags: wpf, binding

I have the following code in my XAML file, with a very simple checkbox.  When the checkbox is checked, it is setting my property to be true.  However, when I uncheck the checkbox, I could see that the value is null, when debugging with a break point in the convertBack function.  I even tried to set IsThreeState = false, but still not working.  Anyone knows why?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <this:DebugValueConverter x:Key="debugConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
 <CheckBox Content="Testing" IsThreeState="False"
                           IsChecked="{Binding CheckBoxValue, 
                                       Converter={StaticResource debugConverter},
                                       FallbackValue=false,TargetNullValue=false}"
                        />
</StackPanel>
```

The CheckBoxValue is a bool property in my view model.

The converter class is:
   public class DebugValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: How is the property set to `null` if it's a `bool`? Post all your code please.

Comment: Please post your `CheckBoxValue` code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simply because you have `TargetNullValue=false` on your `Binding`. That means a value of `false` from your `CheckBoxValue` property will be translated to `null`, which is what your converter sees.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it works after removing TargetNullValue=false.

Comment: I find this an absurd pattern, does anyone have an explanation as to why this would be the default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

IsChecked is often null even when your CheckBox isn't three state.  Either bind to a bool? and use (foo == true) to avoid the null, or bind to a bool and use a converter which converts from bool? to bool by treating null as false.

Comment: The following is a snippet from microsoft documention, it clearly states that I shoudl be able to have only 2 states: "In addition to the checked and unchecked states CheckBox controls can have a third state, indeterminate. If the IsThreeState property is set to true the IsChecked property can be set to null (indeterminate). "

Comment: Yup.  That is the documentation.  As you're discovering, it's not accurate.